The springboot project encountered a port conflict but the process did not exit
I have the simplest springboot project (java17+springboot[2.7.2|3.0.6]+elasticeasrch8) that only integrates the components of ElasticSearch8.
I found that after running the project again (the previous process did not exit), the subsequent project did not exit as expected.
process-2 did not exit as expected
@Component
public class CommonConfig implements DisposableBean {

    @Autowired
    ElasticsearchClient elasticsearchClient;

    // TODO  If commented out, the process did not exit when there was a port conflict
    @Override
    public void destroy() throws Exception {
//        elasticsearchClient._transport().close();
    }
}

In the code, explicitly calling 'elasticsearchClient. _transport(). close()' is required to expect an exit
I have the demo：springboot-demo in GitHub
I tried to explicitly release the thread pool resources and found that the program was able to exit as expected.
What I want to know is:

Why is there such an issue in Elasticsearch 8 that was not encountered in older versions of Elasticsearch

I have also encountered the same problem in other complex projects, integrating a large number of commonly used components. How can I locate this problem (online issues are very distressing for me)


Sincerely looking forward to the clarification from all friends

Please [edit] your question to convert images into text, and use a [code block] for any code you have. Readers can then search the text or run the code to reproduce your issue.
